# What else do I need to save a variable into disc?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'me trying to save a variable into hard drive to load it on my app startup. I do the following:

```
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
votesFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"votes.dat"];
```

Yet, this is creating no file, at least that I can see. When I try to do this:

```
[votes writeToFile:votesFile atomically:YES]; //votes!=nil
```

and then

```
votes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: votesFile];
```

it does nothing for me, votes == nil

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's a NSMutableDictionary

Comment: Does it contain only valid property list objects as [the documentation says is required](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: What are those objects?
The dictionary keys are NSString and the values are NSNumber.

Comment: Seriously?  Did you even bother to read the link?  "instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary".  You should be OK based on what you've said.

Comment: Perhaps Core Data would work better for you? If not, the problem may be that `writeToFile:` isn't finishing either before `initWithContentsOfFile:` is called, or before your app terminates. In that case, you may need to use a different method...

Comment: `writeToFile:atomically:` returns a `BOOL`. Have you checked what `[votes writeToFile:votesFile atomically:YES];` returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a NSDictionary with NSStrings as keys, and NSNumbers as values, those classes are compatible with Archiving and Unarchiving pattern, so you can use NSUserDefaults to store your data, and load it the next time you run the application.

To save your data:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:yourVotesDictionary forKey:aKey];
[defaults synchronize]; //This is very important when you finish saving all your data.
```

To load your data:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableDictionary *votes = [defaults objectForKey:yourNSString];
```

As you can see, NSUserDefaults is a dictionary, and it behaves like that.

Hope it helps,
have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

There can be various errors using writeToFile:atomically: which is why it returns a BOOL. You should have something like:

```
if(![votes writeToFile:votesFile atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"An error occurred");
}
```

If you are getting an error there you have an issue with your NSDictionary.